# From ListView to GridView on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to convert this

```
child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: this.categories.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            double _marginLeft = 0;
            (index == 0) ? _marginLeft = 20 : _marginLeft = 0;
            return new CategoriesCarouselItemWidget(
              marginLeft: _marginLeft,
              category: this.categories.elementAt(index),
            );
          },
        ));
```

to a `GridView` but when I tried something it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: this.categories.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount:  3),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
double _marginLeft = 0;
            (index == 0) ? _marginLeft = 20 : _marginLeft = 0;
    return new CategoriesCarouselItemWidget(
              marginLeft: _marginLeft,
              category: this.categories.elementAt(index),
            );
  },
),
)
```